# is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 (yii2)

Tags: error-handling, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have an website developed with yii2. My full script working fine, but In admin system Create votes not working. That system worked fine before here but now suddenly not working here. The same script working fine on others shared hosting but not working on my hosting. and I check error log of cpanel there no Error Log messages. I never change any script and file. Suddenly it's not working on my hosting. show below my error screen shot.

[image: Screen shot of Error]

Comment: To confirm: it worked before then suddenly stopped working?

Comment: yes, It working fine before 2 days  since 2 years on current hosting but suddenly not working.

Comment: What were the changes in the system? Network? If you can pinpoint the exact moment things broke, you can identify what things changed in that timeframe.

Comment: I got points are, Hosting provider change there server and I have seen they change my Domain NS records.

Comment: have you checked file and folder permissions present on server??

Comment: check and post relevant part of the log